# How do I cut the size of my RSS feed to display in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, rss, feed

I have an iPhone application that reads RSS feeds from a YouTube channel. However, when that view controller loads, it takes forever to load as its downloading a lot of data. How do I make the RSS feed load only several items at a time instead of all at one go?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're currently using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a yahoo pipe, the rss is xml and reading it will require to download it or to use a complex callback based parser.

but you can make a yahoo pipe which takes as input argument the maximum number of post to read and the offset of where to start.

you can take this as a starting point:
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=DjV8JOFS3BGg3vF_TqoASA

after you have made your pipe, you'll need only to change the url from which download the feed to use the piped one.